# Jordan Descomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a Jordan Block, say $J_{\lambda,m}$, what is the Jordan descomposition of $e^{J_{\lambda,m}}$?

Comment: Maybe look at this first? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Using_the_Jordan_canonical_form

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look